# Put JavaScript function in Angularjs file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have my JavaScript with Angularjs like this :

```
...
var propertiesModule = angular.module('xxx.properties', []);

propertiesModule.controller('PropertiesCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'PropertiesService', 'ApplicationService', 'PlatformService', 'Page', function ($scope, $routeParams, PropertiesService, ApplicationService, PlatformService, Page) {
...
}]);
```

I want to call a jQuery functionality like this

```
...
$("input[type=button]").click(function () {
    $("#wrapper tr").prettyTextDiff({
        cleanup: $("#cleanup").is(":checked")
    });
});
...
```

I put in end of my file but the functionality is not executed, why?

Comment: if you mix jquery and angular, you are doing angular wrong

Comment: @anvarik you're right then how without making angular wrong

Comment: try to find a textdiff option for angular instead of using jquery, by googling I found this: https://github.com/matteosuppo/angular-diff

Answer (score 2):

use directives for handling dom. and angular has its own methods for handling dom, using jquery is a bad idea. here is some code to help

```
 app.directive('myDomDirective', function () {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                element.html('You clicked me!');
              // do your stuff
            });

        }
    };
});
```

and a link to help you learn 
[angular directives](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals)